# How to disable XFCE4 keyboard shortcuts in application?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I use Clion IDE when coding on my Arch Linux and I use XFCE4 DE. Some keyboard shortcuts conflicts with IDE shortcuts thus, making the window manager prefered. Is there a way to disable all keyboard shortcuts when Clion window is active ( or another application in general ). I don't want to remove conflicting shortcuts because I use them outside of IDE.

Thanks for help.